# Serialize a column in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to serialize a column in the database named hPriority. I am using the following mysql in php code, but apparently I my statement is wrong as it gives me syntax error:

```
$hPriorityQueryUpdate = mysql_query (" 

SET @counter = 0; 
UPDATE hContactInfo (@counter := @counter +1) as hPr SET hPriority = hPr
WHERE (hType ='$hType')

");
```

THanks for ur help :)

Comment: Use mysqli_/pdo instead of mysql_

Comment: I tried by it gave this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /Users/mohamedahmed/Sites/hotels/business/edit-hotel.php on line 91
0:

Sorry! I am still new to mysql

Comment: When you use it procedural, the first parameter has to be a "mysqli-object". http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php -> google is your friend =)